# UILabel word wrap position moves down in iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios7, uilabel

Am developing an iPhone app which supports from iOS version 4.3 to 7. In one screen am doing auto shrinking UILabel using UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap to fit in single line. In iOS 7, the text is moving down and exceeds the label frame. Please help!!!
[image: Screenshot is attached]

Comment: I have added the screenshot.

Comment: are u doing using coding.. ?

Comment: No.. Am doing everything in Xib only.

Comment: are u doing with autosizing?